# Forward list y iterator

Tags: c++

Estoy viendo como implementar una lista de objetos de una clase:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<forward_list>
#include <string>
using namespace std;



class Persona {
private:
    string m_nombre;
    int m_anios;
public:
    Persona() { m_nombre = ""; m_anios = 0; };
    ~Persona() {};
    string getNombre() { return m_nombre; };
    int getAnios() { return m_anios; };
    void setNombre(string nombre) { m_nombre = nombre; };
    void setAnios(int anios) { m_anios = anios; };
};

int main() {

    Persona p;
    p.setNombre("Juan");
    p.setAnios(20);

    forward_list<Persona> listaPersona;
    forward_list<Persona>::iterator it;

    it = listaPersona.begin();
    listaPersona.push_front(p);
    cout << it->getNombre();

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Lo que pasa es que no se realmente como funciona el iterator y porque no funciona el código. Me aparece una excepción xstring "Infracción de acceso de lectura _Right_data fue 0x4"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes obtener el iterador **después** de insertar, si lo haces, funciona correctamente:

```
listaPersona.push_front(p);
it = listaPersona.begin();
cout << it->getNombre();
```

El iterador que obtuviste antes de insertar, apuntaba a "*nada*", después de insertar el `begin`, cambió a otra cosa. Al des-referenciar el iterador que apuntaba a "*nada*", obtienes el error en tiempo de ejecución.